# Keytool alias does not exist when trying to import new cert, though says there is an existing entry

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I am trying to run the following command to import a new cert

```
sudo keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeypass password -destkeystore /path/to/.keystore -srckeystore mycert.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password-alias myuser
```

I then get the following messages:

```
Importing keystore mycert.pkcs12 to /path/to/.keystore...
Existing entry alias myuser exists, overwrite? [no]:  yes
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <myuser> does not exist
```

I tried deleting the alias out of the keystore and recreating it, but that did not work. I'm not too familiar with this whole process, so I might need a longer explanation.